# Russian symbols works wrong

Tags: shell, command-line, cyrillic

In my command line it doesn't show Russian symbols correctly. Scary symbols instead.

I think I should change character set, but how can it be done? Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: There are many shells.  You'll need to be more specific. OS is likely also relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this command should help you if you work on Windows:

```
chcp 65001
```

This command changes character set of command line to UTF-8.

Comment: My problem was repaired.Thank you!

Comment: If you're on Windows, try changing system locale: `Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Region and Language`, select `Administrative` tab, click Change system locale in the Language for non-Unicode programs. Change that to Russian, then restart your PC (required!). Should fix it permanently (for that machine).